# How do I submit a new package to universe?

Tags: packaging

I've built a package and it is in my PPA here https://launchpad.net/~evarlast/+archive/ppa

I searched a little and found this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/GettingStarted but I could not find a simple howto guide on how to get this into universe.

Answer (score 4):

The workflow for submitting your package is here:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/udd-sponsorship.html

and then keep an eye on the sponsorship queue:

- http://reqorts.qa.ubuntu.com/reports/sponsoring/

I also recommend getting ahold of a [MOTU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Contact) to see if your package is appropriate for Debian as usually submitting to Debian and syncing back into Ubuntu might be a better way to work.

Comment: The first URL should be http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/udd-sponsorship.html

Comment: The first link to udd-sponsorship.html is broken.  Can it be updated?

Comment: Both links seem to be broken. How about https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages?